# ¿Calcular días transcurridos entre dos fechas directamente con vue.js?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

Mi siguiente código en vue.js:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-md-1" for="text-input">Fecha Inicio</label>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="date" v-model="fecha_inicio" class="form-control" placeholder="">
    </div>
    <label class="col-md-1 " for="text-input">Fecha Fin</label>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="date" v-model="fecha_fin" class="form-control" placeholder="">
    </div>
    <label class="col-md-1 " for="text-input">Días Totales</label>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="text" v-model="total_dias" class="form-control" placeholder="Días">
    </div>   
</div>
```

Quiero calcular `fecha_inicio` a `fecha_fin` y mostrarlo en mi `text-input` de Días Totales.

Comment: y de donde obtienes esa fecha o son estáticas? en que formato estan guardados en la bd, que motor de bases de datos usas?

Comment: mysql, tipo de dato es date: formato: YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: te daré un ejemplo pero directo en mysql, realmente no tiene lóigica que hagas esa tarea del lado del frontend, cuando se puede calcular sin problemas desde el gestor de la base de datos

Comment: puedes usar **datediff(fechaActual, fechaVieja);** este sería el ejemplo `select datediff(NOW(), '201-02-19');`